# Is the set S the subspace of C[0,1]? use the properties of the subspace to prove your answer.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the set $S = \left\{ f \in C[0,1] \colon \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx = 0\right\}$ the subspace of $C[0,1]$? Use the properties of the subspace to prove your answer.

I'm not exactly sure how to handle this problem right here... is there anyone that can help?

Comment: Is $\int (f+g)=0$ if $\int f=\int g=0?$ Is $\int (\lambda f)=0$ if $\int f=0$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: Hint: Look at the definition of "subspace": it will say "a set is a subspace if [something]".  Check that [something] is true of this $S$.

Comment: What mfl's comment says is _excatly_ what you should be thinking about when you do this problem.  If you're not, then that's what you need to learn about how to do this kind of problem.

Comment: i got a different sounding definition of subspace and its pretty confusing actually.. could someone help enlighten me about this as well?

Answer (score 2):

A nonempty subset $S$ of a real vector-space $V$ is a subspace if $v+\lambda w\in S$ whenever $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and $v,w\in S$.

So, to check if your $S$ is a subspace of $C[0,1]$, let $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and let $f,g\in S$. Then $f+\lambda g\in S$ if and only if
$$
\int_0^1\big(f(x)+\lambda g(x)\big)\,dx=0\tag{1}
$$
Can you prove (1)?

Hint:
$$
\int_0^1\big(f(x)+\lambda g(x)\big)\,dx
=
\underbrace{\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx}_{\text{What does this equal?}}+\lambda\underbrace{\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx}_{\text{What does this equal?}}
$$

Comment: ..........no D:

Comment: @JL How about now?

Comment: not sure... its been a while since i took calc 2.. im guessing those equal f(x)^2 / 2 ?

Comment: @JL No. How were $f_1$ and $f_2$ defined in the first place? This has nothing to do with Calc 2.